# ERROR: operator does not exist: date = character varying

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot

I have this problem:

this query in PostgreSQL PG Admin work fine:

```
SELECT ST_AsGeoJSON(t1.\*) as extent FROM ricepest.forecast t1 where state = 'Andhra Pradesh' AND dist = 'Ananthapur' AND date_id = '2023-01-01';
```

but in spring-boot with hibernate i wrote a service like this:

```
@Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "SELECT ST_AsGeoJSON(t1.*) as extent FROM ricepest.state t1 where state = :val")
    List<GetFeature> getFeatureByStateIdService(@Param("val") String val);
    
    @Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "SELECT ST_AsGeoJSON(t1.*) as extent FROM ricepest.district t1 where state = :state_val AND dist = :dist_val")
    List<GetFeature> getFeatureByStateIdService(@Param("state_val") String state_val, @Param("dist_val") String dist_val);
    
    @Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "SELECT ST_AsGeoJSON(t1.*) as extent FROM ricepest.forecast t1 where state = :state_val AND dist = :dist_val AND date_id = :from_date")
    List<GetFeature> getFeatureByStateIdService(@Param("state_val") String state_val, @Param("dist_val") String dist_val, @Param("from_date") String from_date);
    
    public static interface GetFeature {
        String getExtent();
    }
```

This is my java Controller:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/feature")
    public ResponseEntity<List<GetFeature>> getFeatureByStateIdService(@RequestBody RequestInputs reqInputs) {
        System.out.println("The state and district input value for getFeature : " + reqInputs.getState_id() + " and " + reqInputs.getDist() + " and " + reqInputs.getFromdate_id());
        List<GetFeature> extent;
        if (reqInputs.getDist().equalsIgnoreCase("0") || reqInputs.getDist().equalsIgnoreCase("-- SELECT DISTRICT--")) {
            extent = pestServiceRepository.getFeatureByStateIdService(reqInputs.getState_id());
        } else if (reqInputs.getFromdate_id().equalsIgnoreCase("0") || reqInputs.getFromdate_id().equalsIgnoreCase("-- SELECT DATE--")) {
            extent = pestServiceRepository.getFeatureByStateIdService(reqInputs.getDist());
        } else {
            extent = pestServiceRepository.getFeatureByStateIdService(reqInputs.getState_id(), reqInputs.getDist(), reqInputs.getFromdate_id());
        }
        if (!extent.isEmpty()) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(extent, HttpStatus.OK);
        } else {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }
    }
```

I have this ERROR:

```
ERROR: operator does not exist: date = character varying
  Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

I am not getting what has went wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

In pgAdmin, the literal `'2023-01-01'` is being parsed as a date value, not a text value, because of the context of the expression. In the Java code with Spring Boot and Hibernate, the parameter has been explicitly specified to be of class `String`. PostgreSQL doesn't perform implicit conversions of text values to date values prior to the comparison. There is a fundamental difference between parsing a SQL statement and evaluating a statement with explicit parameters. Either pass the parameter as a date, or explicitly cast the text value to a date in the query. Passing the parameter as the intended type is the preferred approach.

The following statements, which can be run in pgAdmin, demonstrate the differences:

```
-- because '2023-06-06' is parsed as a date, this query will not raise an exception
SELECT current_date = '2023-06-06';

-- because test_date is explicitely made a date, this query will not raise an exception
-- this is analogous to passing a date value to a parameterized query
WITH t(test_date) AS (
  VALUES ('2023-06-06'::date)
)
SELECT current_date = t.test_date
FROM t;

-- this query will raise an exception due to type differences
-- there is no context to cause PostgreSQL to parse '2023-06-06' as a date
WITH t(test_date) AS (
  VALUES ('2023-06-06')
)
SELECT current_date = t.test_date
FROM t;

-- because of the explicit type cast, this query will not raise an exception
-- this is similar to passing a string and explicitly casting it to date in the SELECT
WITH t(test_date) AS (
  VALUES ('2023-06-06')
)
SELECT current_date = t.test_date::date
FROM t;
```

Comment: The nice solution is to declare date parameters that are passed to the query `LocalDate` in Java. Transferring dates as strings to the database is discouraged. You also wouldn’t pass numbers as strings (I hope).